# Convert dict with variable length list of dicts to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary with as values a list of dictionaries and these lists are of variable length. I have tried a lot, but can't get the data properly transformed to a Pandas dataframe.

The data looks like this:

```
{key1: [{'column5': 40, 'column1': 1, 'column2': 6, 'column3': 170, 'column4': 300}], 
key2: [{'column5': 6, 'column1': 33, 'column2': 5, 'column3': 76, 'column4': 13}], 
key3: [{'column5': 7, 'column1': 44, 'column2': 2, 'column3': 67, 'column4': 13}, {'column5': 45, 'column1': 400, 'column2': 100, 'column3': 12, 'column4': 145}]}
```

I want to get a frame like this:

```
      column1  column2 column3   ..
key1  1        6       170
key2  33       5       76
key3  33       2       67
key3  400      100     12
 .
 .
```

I either get errors like 'Arrays must all be of same length' when using pd.DataFrame.from_records and when using orient=index, the data is still as a dictionary placed in the dataframe. Some of the things I've tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
df.transpose() //Data is not properly placed in the dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataset, orient='index') //Data is not properly placed in the dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataset) //Gives error about length of arrays

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataset).T //Gives error about length of arrays
```

How should I go about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post your desired dataframe?  Also your dictionary is not defined correctly

Comment: I've edited the original post, hopefully it is more clear now. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Can you please just post the desired dataframe as text, formatted as you want, not a description of it?

Comment: How do you want me to write a dataframe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, I've edited the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176390/discussion-between-stefan1993-and-user3483203).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Setup***

```
dct = {'key1': [{'column5': 40, 'column1': 1, 'column2': 6, 'column3': 170, 'column4': 300}],'key2': [{'column5': 6, 'column1': 33, 'column2': 5, 'column3': 76, 'column4': 13}],'key3': [{'column5': 7, 'column1': 44, 'column2': 2, 'column3': 67, 'column4': 13}, {'column5': 45, 'column1': 400, 'column2': 100, 'column3': 12, 'column4': 145}]}
```

Using a list comprehension to slightly restructure your input dataset:

```
pd.DataFrame([{'key': k, **i} for  k, v in dct.items() for i in v])

   column1  column2  column3  column4  column5   key
0        1        6      170      300       40  key1
1       33        5       76       13        6  key2
2       44        2       67       13        7  key3
3      400      100       12      145       45  key3
```

To help better understand *why* this works, here is the list of dictionaries created by the list comprehension:

```
[{'key': 'key1', 'column5': 40, 'column1': 1, 'column2': 6, 'column3': 170, 'column4': 300}, {'key': 'key2', 'column5': 6, 'column1': 33, 'column2': 5, 'column3': 76, 'column4': 13}, {'key': 'key3', 'column5': 7, 'column1': 44, 'column2': 2, 'column3': 67, 'column4': 13}, {'key': 'key3', 'column5': 45, 'column1': 400, 'column2': 100, 'column3': 12, 'column4': 145}]
```